# Removing specific character from text in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

My Spark dataframe column has some weird character in there.  I wanted to remove that.When I select that particular column and do .show() I see it as below

`Dominant technology firm seeks ambitious, assertive, confident, headstrong salesperson to lead our organization into the next era! If you are ready to thrive in a highly competitive environment, this is the job for you. ¥ Superior oral and written communication skills¥ Extensive experience with negotiating and closing sales ¥ Outspoken ¥ Thrives in competitive environment¥ Self-reliant and able to succeed in an independent setting  ¥ Manage portfolio of clients ¥ Aggressively close sales to exceed quarterly quotas ¥ Deliver expertise to clients as needed ¥ Lead the company into new markets`            |

The character as you see is ¥.

I wrote the following code to remove this from the 'description' column of data frame

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

charReplace=udf(lambda x: x.replace('¥',''))

train_cleaned=train_triLabel.withColumn('dsescription',charReplace('description'))
train_cleaned.show(2,truncate=False)
```

It however throws an error:

```
File "/Users/i854319/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/Users/i854319/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1563, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(lambda x: returnType.toInternal(f(*x)), it)
  File "<ipython-input-32-864efe6f3257>", line 3, in <lambda>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However when I do it on a test string the character is recognized by the replace method.

```
s='hello ¥'
print s
s.replace('¥','')
​
hello ¥
Out[37]:
'hello '
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Unicode literal:

```
charReplace = udf(lambda x: x.replace(u'¥',''))
```